# Add external SD Card in BlackBerry simulator

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to add the external SD Card in my BlackBerry simulator for creating the data base.I'm using this way  to add -

1.create folder and give name-SDCard.
2.in the simulator click on-simulate.
3.choose change SD Card.
4.select  your folder SDCard.
5.click on close.

but even than when I run the project ,It's showing an error that "SD Card not found".
Any help???

Answer (score 2):

I have got the solution -
After creating the SD Card folder we have to make it share before simulate in simulator.
 and the another process is same.